# How to compile ASP .NET website on 32-bit machine & deploy it on 64-bit machine

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm working on restructuring a website written in ASP .NET. I'm working on Vista machine with 2010. The intended deployment server is 64-bit machine running IIS.

Now, I know that exactly same code will work on both the machines, but I may have to compile the code differently for the deployment server. Can anyone guide me regarding correct settings for this & place to change these settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set "Any CPU" as a Platform in your project properties. You can access it through

Build->Configuration Manager...

And you site will work on both x32 and x64